# How to retrieve the Id of the Last inserted data in to a "New Page" in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a sign up page in PHP.
When the submit button is clicked, it should show the registration No. on a NEW PAGE,
(like "Your registration is successful and your registration No. is____").
I Know how to show the last inserted ID on the same page.
but how to display the same on a NEW PAGE using `mysql_insert_id()`?

Below is the SIGN UP PAGE.

```
include 'connect1.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $qual = $_POST['qual'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    $sql="INSERT INTO registeredparticipants (Name, DateOfBirth, Address, PhoneNumber, EmailID, Qualification)" .
            "VALUES ( '$name','$dob', '$address', '$number', '$email', '$qual' )";
    $res=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($res)
    {
        header('location: welcome.php');
    }
    else
    {
        die ("Query Failed !!" . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

When submit button is clicked, "welcome" page will be loaded.
and I would like to display the ID of the last inserted data in "welcome" page.
ID of the above table is "Reg_no." How to display it on "welcome" page?

Comment: Also show some code so we can help you better way.. what you tried till now ?

Comment: @Thaslam many people have replied try that.

Comment: i tried everything... Nothing working.. Could you please provide the code for the next page? How to use session  on the above page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways for this answer using $_GET and $_SESSION, get will show id in url if you dont want that use session for that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ......";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $_SESSION['registration_no']=$last_id;
    header("Location:newpage.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

in newpage.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

Your registration is successful and ur registration No. is <?php echo $_SESSION['registration_no']; ?>
```

i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can put into the url you are using to redirect like `header("location:new_page.php?id=".$last_insert_id)` and get from `$_GET['id']` on new_page.php

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by either get | post | COOKIE | SESSION

1. header("location:new_page.php?id=".$last_inserted_id) and get from $_GET['id'] on new_page.php
2. In html form hidden format " and get it from $_POST['id'] on new_page.php
3. [COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)
4. [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session` to store such value and retrieve it on any page you want like-

```
session_start();

//your code....
$_SESSION['reg_no'] = $last_insert_id;
```

than on any page you can retrieve it -

```
session_start();

$reg_no = $_SESSION['reg_no'];
echo "Your registration is successful and ur registration No. is ".$reg_no;
```